# JS функция не видит переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

У меня динамически подключаются все файлы шаблона, грубо говоря примерно так:

```
index.php: подключается template.php
views/template.php: шаблон. Подключается всё из папки template
template/style.css: работает нормально
         custom.js: работает почти нормально
```

Проблема в том, что в JS файле функции, вызываемые из шаблона, не видят переменных jQuery, которые занимаются получением тегов и шаблона:

```
function selectOrder(order) {
        var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
        $('option:selected', 'select[name="privelege"]').removeAttr('selected');
        $('select[name="privelege"]').find('option[value="'+order+'"]').attr("selected",true);
        switch(order) {
            case 'vip':
                setOrderPrice(10);
                inst.open();
                break;
```

Отладчик пишет, что `inst` не объявлена. **JS** грузится в самом конце, после **jQuery**. При этом, всё остальное работает (например скролл вверх). Я уже пробовал помещать всё или только **jquery** в `$(document).ready()`, но ничего.

Comment: не объявлена или undefined/null ?

Comment: Пишет Не объявлена

Comment: скопируйте сообщение об ошибке

Comment: ReferenceError: inst is not defined Извиняюсь, она всё таки undefined

Comment: да нет, как раз не определена. И это очень странно, т.к. в этом коде она не может быть не определенной. Может ошибка в другом месте ? Или ваш проект не пересобрался.

Comment: Проверьте мой проект на GitHub: https://github.com/ZappTeam/demo/

Comment: это custom.js ? такой проблемы в нем нет. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZappTeam/demo/master/template/js/custom.js

Comment: Нет, я ради интереса вынес эту и пр. функции в файл functions.js. В нём и проблема

Comment: теперь точно ничего не будет работать :) потому что вы эти функции закрыли в скопе анонимки, это значит, что их не видно снаружи теперь никак

Comment: Увы, это не помогло. Помогло перенести эти функции прямо в шаблон, но этого костыля очень хотелось бы избежать

Comment: Оказывается, проблема давно решена... Просто сисадмин додумался на демо-домене включить ускорение JS))

Comment: то о чем я говорил